# Python Regex matching on unexpected parts of search string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a page using regex (Python 2.7; IPython QTConsole).  The page is a .txt pulled from a web directory that I grabbed using `urllib2`

```
>>> import re
>>> Z = '[A-Z]{2}Z[0-9]{3}.*?\\$\\$'
>>> snippet = re.search(Z, page, re.DOTALL)
>>> snippet = snippet.group() # Only including the first part for brevity.
'PZZ570-122200-\nPOINT ARENA TO POINT REYES 10 TO 60 NM OFFSHORE-\n249 AM PDT FRI SEP 12 2014\n.TODAY...SW WINDS 5 KT. WIND WAVES 2 FT OR LESS.\nNW SWELL 3 TO 5 FT AT 12 SECONDS. PATCHY FOG IN THE MORNING.\n.TONIGHT...W WINDS 10 KT. WIND WAVES 2 FT OR LESS.'
```

I want to search for the newline followed by a period.  I'd like to get the first and second occurrences as below.  The objective is to parse the information between the first and second (and subsequent) `\n\.` delimiters.  I know I could do look-around, but I'm having trouble making the lookahead greedy.  Further, I can't figure out why the following doesn't work.

```
>>> pat = r"\n\."
>>> s = re.search(pat, snippet.group(), re.DOTALL)
>>> e = re.search(pat, snippet.group()[s.end():], re.DOTALL)
```

The `s` above works, but I get a strange result for `e`.

```
>>> [s.group(), s.start(), e.group(), e.end()]
['\n.', 90, '\n.', 110]

>>> snippet.group()[s.start():e.end()]
'\n.TODAY...SW WINDS 5'

>>> snippet.group()[e.start():e.end()]
' 5'
```

I guess there's some formatting in `snippet.group()` that's hidden?  If that's the case, then it's strange that some newlines are explicit as if `snippet.group()` is raw, and others are hidden.  Why are `e.group()`, and `snippet.group()[e.start():e.end()]` different?

I apologize if this question has already been addressed.  I couldn't find anything related.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: you might have more luck with `re.split()` for your stated objective

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thanks very much.  I'm still curious about the behavior above.

Comment: no idea, would have to spend a lot of time debugging :(

Comment: Totally not worth it :).  Thanks.  I'll post something in this space if I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a string in python, it might be easier to use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) or [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

e.g.:

```
"1\n.2\n.3".split("\n.")
```